Crystal Report Viewer Changing Font
I created a report in crystal report 2020. In this report i have a chart using font arial.
When this report gets loaded to crystal report viewer via VS it's bolding the font in the chart. However, the rest of the reports font is fine.
I'm using Crystal Report Runtime SP36.
